# How can I use variable instead of 'Summer-Collection' in my query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I make this conditions with eloquent? I want all records with `product` and `category` table whose `url_name` equals to `$variable_name`.

Here is the code:

```
 \App\Product::with(['category' => function ($query) {

      $query->whereHas('url_name','Summer-Collection');
     
 }])->get();
```

Comment: Am I to assume you are getting an error about `$variable_name` not being defined? If so you will just need to add `use ($variable_name)` after the function parameters to put it within scope. If not, please add more detail to your question. Or even if that is the problem, include it in your question.

Comment: yes, It says undefined variable

Comment: Read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) about anonymous functions in php. Check out example #3 on inheriting variables from the parent scope

Comment: Cleanest solution is `Product::with(['category' => fn($q) => $q->whereHas('url_name', $variable_name)])->get();` No need to import variables from parent scope with arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `url_name` is on the `category` table, and you have a relation setup on the `Product` Model you would do something like this.

```
 $variable = 'Summer-Collection';

 \App\Product::with(['category'])->whereHas('category', function($query) use($variable) {
       $query->where('url_name','=',$variable);
 })->get();
```

Comment: You edited out a key part of their question, so I don't think this addresses the error that the OP is intending to ask about (well after an edit it does in passing..). I also don't think what they had was incorrect - [docs on constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: @BrianThompson, I realized that after I edited, but the query on the OP wouldn't work as `whereHas` works with relationships and cannot be used as a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the variable to the closure using `use`:

```php
$variable_name = "something";
\App\Product::with(['category' => function ($query) use($variable_name) {
    $query->where('url_name', $variable_name);
}])->get();
```

Comment: yes, Now its working fine. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulMoiz If it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: can you please guide me which jQuery event I can use to get the products between Prices using price range slider?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz I have no experience in frontend development, sorry bro.

Comment: How can I show products using Load More Button instead of pagination. any idea?